# How to you import a 3rd party framework as a dependency using Swift Package Manager?

Tags: swift, package

I'm trying to create a project using Swift Package Manager, but I'm running into issues trying to include the Fabric.framework.

Here is my Package.swift

```
let package = Package(
    name: "TestPackage",
    platforms: [
        .iOS(.v10), .macOS(.v10_12)
    ],
    products: [
        // Products define the executables and libraries produced by a package, and make them visible to other packages.
        .library(
            name: "TestPackage",
            targets: ["TestPackageSwift", "TestPackageObjC"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [        
        .package(url: "https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git", from: "4.8.2"),
        .package(path: "./TestPackage/Libraries/Fabric.framework"),
    ],
    targets: [
        // Targets are the basic building blocks of a package. A target can define a module or a test suite.
        // Targets can depend on other targets in this package, and on products in packages which this package depends on.
        .target(
            name: "TestPackageSwift",
            dependencies: ["Alamofire", "Fabric"],
            path:"./TestPackage/Sources/Swift"),
        .target(
            name: "TestPackageObjC",
            dependencies: ["Fabric"],
            path:"./TestPackage/Sources/ObjC"),
        .testTarget(
            name: "TestPackageTests",
            dependencies: ["TestPackageSwift", "TestPackageObjC"],
            path:"./TestPackageTests/Sources"),
    ]
)
```

And here is the error I am getting:

```
error: ./TestPackage/Libraries/Fabric.framework has no Package.swift manifest
```

Is this even possible?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Did you got any solution for this problem?